# Display of stacked column chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm rendering a stacked column chart. My "problem" is that the columns appear to be located one behind the other, instead of one on top of the other, add a "depth" to the column so to speak.

Is there a setting to get the column to appear in a "flat" manner, one on top of the other?

Thx..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set stacking parameter [refer this link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.stacking)

Comment: I did that, I think that the problem was with the shadow. Thanks.